# Is it possible to establish IMAP Idle connection directly with Imap server from client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I want to make a IMAP IDLE connection from client browser side with javascript coding. But I am not sure we can do it in javascript.

I came to know about this [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) but from what I searched it seems it is a server side coding.. I want to maintain the imap connection from client side.. Is there a way to do it? Any libraries or plugins available for this?

Comment: I want to do Imap IDLE connection establishment using javascript..